# How can I avoid looping through this array twice?

Tags: solidity

My code is as follows:

```
/**
 *
 * @notice Returns a Sale array with all the sales that have not ended.
 *
 */
function getOngoingSales() public view returns(Sale[] memory) {
    uint256 _ongoingSalesCounter = 0;

    for(uint i = 0; i<sales.length; i++) {
        if (sales[i].ended == false) _ongoingSalesCounter++;
    }

    Sale[] memory _ongoingSales = new Sale[](_ongoingSalesCounter);

    uint256 _pos = 0;
    for(uint i = 0; i<sales.length; i++) {
        
        if (sales[i].ended == false) {
            _ongoingSales[_pos] = sales[i];
            _pos ++;
        }
    }

    return _ongoingSales;
}
```

The problem is that I have to loop twice the array to get to my wanted result. Is there a more effective way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you combine the two loops into a single one where it will push `sales[i]` into `_ongoingSales` once `ended` is false?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to combine the two loops into one,

```
/**
 *
 * @notice Returns a Sale array with all the sales that have not ended.
 *
 */
function getOngoingSales() public view returns(Sale[] memory) {
    Sale[] memory _ongoingSales;

    for(uint i = 0; i<sales.length; i++) {
        if (sales[i].ended == false) _ongoingSales.push(sales[i]);
    }

    return _ongoingSales;
}
```

Before time complexity: O(2n)

After time complexity: O(n)

Comment: This can't be done because .push() is not available in memory arrays.